# Counting rows from table

Tags: mysql, sql, count, rows

I have a problem. It seems easy to resolve, but in fact I don't know why it is not working !

I have two tables :

```sql
HOSTS(id, hostgroup_id)
HOSTGROUPS(id, name)
```

With these inserted rows :

```
HOSTS
________________________
id    |    hostgroup_id
________________________
1     |    1
2     |    1
3     |    2
4     |    NULL         -- a host can have no hostgroup
________________________


HOSTGROUPS
________________________
id    |    name
________________________
1     |    ARM
2     |    Spark
3     |    Pyro
________________________
```

With that, I just want to count number of hosts in each hostgroups.
Here is my SQL query :

```
SELECT HG.name, COUNT(H.id) AS count
FROM HOSTS H, HOSTGROUPS HG
WHERE H.hostgroup = HG.id
UNION DISTINCT
SELECT HG.name, 0 AS count
FROM HOSTS H, HOSTGROUPS HG
WHERE (H.hostgroup = HG.id) = FALSE
```

And here is my result :

```
_____________________
name     |     count
_____________________
ARM      |     2     -- OK
Spark    |     0     -- NOPE, INTENDED 1
Pyro     |     0     -- OK
ARM      |     0     -- NOPE, DUPLICATED ROW
_____________________
```

And finally, here's what I am waiting for :

```
_____________________
name     |     count
_____________________
ARM      |     2
Spark    |     1
Pyro     |     0
_____________________
```

Thanks for your answers guys ! :)

Comment: Add GROUP BY clauses to the selects. (And remove the `;`... Does your query really execute?)

Comment: @jarlh Woops, the `;` was not here at the origin !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT hg.name,
(SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM HOSTS h
WHERE h.hostgroup_id = hg.id)
FROM HOSTGROUPS hg
```

Comment: It gives me exactly what I want. Thanks for your help ! :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use a left join with group by

```
SELECT HG.name, COUNT(*) AS count
FROM HOSTS H 
LEFT JOIN  HOSTGROUPS HG ON ( H.hostgroup = HG.id)
GROUP BY HG.name;
```

Comment: Gives me `NULL | count 1` instead of `Pyro | count 0`

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT HG.name, COUNT(H.id) AS count
FROM HOSTS H, HOSTGROUPS HG
WHERE H.hostgroup = HG.id(+)
group by H.id;
```

Hope this helps